# pptpclinet Error: either "to" is duplicate, or "uid" is a garbage

Tags: pptp

I use Arch linux, and using `pptp` to connect VPN.  Following the Arch wiki steps, it worked before I updated Arch linux. I updated Arch following Arch homepage commands as:

```
pacman -Syuw                           # download packages
rm /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt  # remove conflicting file
pacman -Su                             # perform upgrade
```

then I ran `pptpclient` will get either

```
Error: either "to" is duplicate, or "uid" is a garbage
```

or after routed and pinged long time I get the following error:

```
Modem hangup
Sent 1002073833 bytes, received 0 bytes
MPPE disabled
Connection terminated
Waiting for 1 child processes...
script /etc/ppp/ip-down, pid 2726
Script /etc/ppp/ip-down finished (pid 2726), status = 0x0
```

I do not know what is wrong, but I feel like `pptpclient` cannot receive any data after routed.

Does anyone have any ideas how to proceed?

UPDATED:

when I debug `pptpclient` using command:

```
sudo pon myVpn debug dump logfd 2 nodetach
```

then the debug info as:

```
pppd options in effect:
debug           # (from command line)
nodetach                # (from command line)
logfd 2         # (from command line)
dump            # (from command line)
noauth          # (from /etc/ppp/options)
name dxcqcv             # (from /etc/ppp/peers/myVpn)
remotename PPTP         # (from /etc/ppp/peers/myVpn)
                # (from /etc/ppp/options)
pty pptp p1.hk3.flydidu.com --nolaunchpppd              # (from /etc/ppp/peers/myVpn)
crtscts         # (from /etc/ppp/options)
                # (from /etc/ppp/options)
asyncmap 0              # (from /etc/ppp/options)
mru 1400                # (from /etc/ppp/options)
mtu 1400                # (from /etc/ppp/options)
silent          # (from /etc/ppp/options)
lcp-echo-failure 4              # (from /etc/ppp/options)
lcp-echo-interval 30            # (from /etc/ppp/options)
hide-password           # (from /etc/ppp/options)
ipparam myVpn           # (from /etc/ppp/peers/myVpn)
proxyarp                # (from /etc/ppp/options)
usepeerdns              # (from /etc/ppp/peers/myVpn)
nobsdcomp               # (from /etc/ppp/options)
nodeflate               # (from /etc/ppp/options)
require-mppe-128                # (from /etc/ppp/peers/myVpn)
noipx           # (from /etc/ppp/options)
using channel 8
Using interface ppp0


Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/4
***Error: either "to" is duplicate, or "uid" is a garbage.***
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0x80de6b20> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <mru 1400> <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xd2626b7a> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0x80de6b20> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <mru 1400> <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xd2626b7a> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x0 magic=0xd2626b7a]
rcvd [LCP EchoReq id=0x0 magic=0x80de6b20]
sent [LCP EchoRep id=0x0 magic=0xd2626b7a]
rcvd [CHAP Challenge id=0x7d <94f97c87ea84a9097b3910d403d0ab14>, name = "pptpd"]
Warning - secret file /etc/ppp/chap-secrets has world and/or group access
added response cache entry 0
sent [CHAP Response id=0x7d <289521c7e2bf1d1a2d3bd8addb8b494e0000000000000000d8ae891c6114fbe4097ef6b89fef69e516540b92f2198a3e00>, name = "dxcqcv"]
rcvd [LCP EchoRep id=0x0 magic=0x80de6b20]
rcvd [CHAP Success id=0x7d "S=A37F545150DBF921600B0B681B1E1ADDD7238617"]
response found in cache (entry 0)
CHAP authentication succeeded
sent [CCP ConfReq id=0x1 <mppe +H -M +S -L -D -C>]
rcvd [CCP ConfReq id=0x1 <mppe +H -M +S -L -D -C>]
sent [CCP ConfAck id=0x1 <mppe +H -M +S -L -D -C>]
rcvd [CCP ConfAck id=0x1 <mppe +H -M +S -L -D -C>]
MPPE 128-bit stateless compression enabled
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]

rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 10.10.0.1>]
sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x1 <addr 10.10.0.1>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfRej id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x2 <addr 10.10.0.21> <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 8.8.4.4>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x3 <addr 10.10.0.21> <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 8.8.4.4>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfAck id=0x3 <addr 10.10.0.21> <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 8.8.4.4>]
Cannot determine ethernet address for proxy ARP
local  IP address 10.10.0.21
remote IP address 10.10.0.1
primary   DNS address 8.8.8.8
secondary DNS address 8.8.4.4
Script /etc/ppp/ip-up started (pid 8055)
Script /etc/ppp/ip-up finished (pid 8055), status = 0x0
```

when this time the ppp0 was created, then I routed as:

```
sudo ip route replace default dev ppp0
```

It should be worked like before, but it didn't after updated Arch, and show error message as:

```
Script pptp p1.hk3.flydidu.com --nolaunchpppd finished (pid 8047), status = 0x0
Modem hangup
**Connect time 2.0 minutes.
Sent 851273846 bytes, received 0 bytes.**
Script /etc/ppp/ip-down started (pid 8097)
MPPE disabled
sent [LCP TermReq id=0x2 "MPPE disabled"]
Connection terminated.
Waiting for 1 child processes...
  script /etc/ppp/ip-down, pid 8097
Script /etc/ppp/ip-down finished (pid 8097), status = 0x0
```

Answer (score 1):

That message `Error: either "to" is duplicate, or "uid" is a garbage` is a message from the `ip` command which pptpclient presumably uses to set up the connection. It's its way to say that the command line which it was given is syntactically invalid, and that it can't parse it.

Since you claim it started after an upgrade of your Arch installation, it's likely that this is just a bug in the most recent version of the `pptpclient` program.

I would file a bug in the program's bug tracker.

Comment: thanks a lot, and I update my error info and details for someone need.